# Send multiple messages in a BizTalk orchestration

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a content repository where documents will be scanned and indexed. Upon indexing these documents a xml representation of the document content is being sent to a BizTalk orchestration.

I'm using a value in that message to send a request to a LOB system for some history information.

Based on how many  history nodes come back I may need to send 0 to n messages to the LOB to update existing records.

My question is, how can I create and send multiple messages of the same type to the LOB with different data content from within my orchestration?

Data flow: Content Repo message into BT Orchestration -> send Get request to LOB based on an ID value in the Content Repo message to retrieve history data -> Interrogate response to determine if there is more than one record in LOB that requires update -> Send 0 to n update messages with unique content to the LOB to perform updates

Answer (score 0):

The response schema from the Content Repo could be packaged into an envelope. You can then debatch the (envelope with the multiple responses) and send them off acordingly to do the updates.